# C++ 20 Concepts: Require operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to understand how to declare a concept that requires a particular operator is overloaded for a given type. Lets say I have the following function that takes a vector of an arbitrary type and prints it to `std::cout`:

```cpp
template<typename printable>
void print_vector(const std::vector<printable>& vec) 
{
    std::cout << '{';
    for (const printable &item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << ',';
    }
    std::cout << '}';
}
```

This code will work just fine if the type `printable` has an overloaded `<<` operator, but if it doesn't, then it fails with a very unhelpful compiler error. I feel like I should be able to somehow declare a concept that requires a type has a valid `<<` operator defined, and use that concept in the function declaration, so that I can get a more useful compiler error, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can use `static_assert` inside your template function to check your condition (e.g. << operator) and print a more convenient error message.

Comment: @AdrianMaire From experience it often happens that the compiler spits out the full error no match for operator<< even with a failing `static_assert`. And a `static_assert` can have unintended consequences (as opposed to SFINAE or concepts). For instance if there is another `print_vector` which would be found by ADL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template <class T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& os, T a)
{
    os << a;
};


template<Printable T>
void print_vector(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
  std::cout << '{';
  for (const auto &item : vec) {
    std::cout << item << ',';
  }
  std::cout << '}';
}
```

If you wish you could also make it more generic to operate on `basic_ostream`.

---

Here is the clang error message:

> ```
> <source>:30:5: error: no matching function for call to 'print_vector'
>     print_vector(x);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:19:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with T = X]
> void print_vector(std::vector<T> vec) {
>      ^
> <source>:18:10: note: because 'X' does not satisfy 'Printable'
> template<Printable T>
>          ^
> <source>:10:9: note: because 'os << a' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'X')
>     os << a;
>        ^
> ```

and gcc:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'auto test()':
> <source>:30:19: error: use of function 'void print_vector(std::vector<T>) [with T = X]' with unsatisfied constraints
>    30 |     print_vector(x);
>       |                   ^
> <source>:19:6: note: declared here
>    19 | void print_vector(std::vector<T> vec) {
>       |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:19:6: note: constraints not satisfied
> <source>: In instantiation of 'void print_vector(std::vector<T>) [with T = X]':
> <source>:30:19:   required from here  
> <source>:8:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'Printable<T>' [with T = X]
> <source>:8:21:   in requirements with 'std::ostream& os', 'T a' [with T = X]    
> <source>:10:9: note: the required expression '(os << a)' is invalid    
>    10 |     os << a;
>       |     ~~~^~~~
> cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
> ```